# How can display products coming from ajax search result in django?

Tags: html, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

**Problem**
*The search feature is working and the values are retrieved from the Django views search function but now I'm not getting how to display those values in my Django project.*

*Can anyone here can help me through this.*

*The code is attached below.*

**JS**

```
 $('#searchsubmit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        q = $('#search').val();
        console.log(q);
        updateContentBySearch(q);
  });

function updateContentBySearch(q) {
    var data = {};
    data['search_by'] = q
    // data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = $('#searchform [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'main:Search' %}",
        data: {
          'search_by': q
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // do your thing
        }
      });

    }
```

**VIEW**

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('search_by')
    print(q)
    product = Products.objects.all()
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    transaction = transactions.objects.filter(productID__name__icontains=q,status='Enable').order_by('productID')
    print(transaction)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:home'),{'products':product, 'transaction': transaction , 'cart_product_form':cart_product_form})
    # return redirect(request, 'main/home.html',{'products':product, 'transaction': transaction , 'cart_product_form':cart_product_form})
```

**HTML FORM**

```
form class="d-flex col-md-6" id="searchform">
   <div class="input-group mb-3" style="text-align:center">
  <input name="q" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search">
  <button class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2" type="submit" id="searchsubmit">Search</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**HTML PRODUCT DISPLAY**

```
 {% regroup transaction by productID as ProductList %}
  {% for productID in ProductList %}
  <div class="col-sm-3 productID" >
    <div class="product">
      <a href="{% url 'main:product-detail' productID.grouper.id %}" class="img-prod"><img class="img-fluid" src={{productID.grouper.product_image.url}} alt="" height="200px">
        <span class="status id_discount">%</span>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="text py-3 pb-4 px-3 text-center">
        <h3><a href="#">{{productID.grouper}}</a></h3>
        <div class="d-flex text-center">
          <div class="" style="width: 310px;">
            <p class="price"><span class="mr-2 price-dc id_price"> </span> Rs. <span class="price-sale"> </span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
          
         
         
        <!-- <div class="bottom-area d-flex px-3">
          <div class="m-auto d-flex"> -->
            <form id='transactionIDValue' class="d-inline" method="post">
              <div class="row">
                <select class="col-md-8 form-select tranactionID" id="ItemID" style="">
                  {% for val in productID.list %}
                      <option transID={{val.id}} price={{val.Price}} discount={{val.discount_percentage}} sale_price={{val.get_sale}} class="price_value" >{{val.AUID}} - {{val.Description}}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              {{cart_product_form.quantity}}
            </div>
              {% csrf_token %}
              <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; background: transparent;">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2 Id_submit" value="Add To Cart">
              <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2">Add to Cart</button> -->
            </form>
            
          </div>
          <!-- </div>
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

*This code gives me the search results but I'm not getting how to show those values here again. This is the home page for products and when I search I want that search result are displayed on the homepage the same way as before.*

**SEARCH RESULTS IMAGE**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I use AJAX requests I send the data to a view through get.

```
function get_data(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'your view' %}',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'query': query,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                if (data.items.length > 0) {
        var $html_content = '';
                    for (var $i = 0; $i < data.items.length; $i++) {
                        $contact_data += '<tr>';

                        # Format HTML ($html_content += 'your html from data';
                    }
                }

                $('#contact_content').html($html_content );
                $('#navigation').html(data.page.render);

            } else {
                console.log(data.error_message);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Couldnt collect data')
        }
    });
}
```

In the view I do:

```
def get_items(request):
data = {'error': True}

try:
    query = int(request.GET.get('query', None))
except:
    query = None

if query:
    data['error'] = False
data['items'] = [] #list with your data
else:
    data['error_message'] = 'No valid page index was given'

return JsonResponse(data)
```